# Testing with languages not available on Android devices with cellular connection

Tags: android, testing, mobile

I'm attempting to test using a language other than what is listed under Languages for a Samsung S5, an older Samsung device with an Ice Cream sandwich OS, and a Motorola device with JellyBean OS. My available languages under Language & Input do not include the ones I need. My Android tablets have all languages, so those are fine. It is just occurring on devices that have cellular service (Sprint & Verizon). I have installed language packs for my desired languages, have installed a GPS faker, and have set my keyboards to include the languages. All without luck.

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with customer support at Samsung, they said they cannot add languages to a device. They suggested installing language packs (which I did); however, that didn't work. Since this occurs with a Motorola device, as well, it is quite disappointing for a tester needing to test in languages other than the ones from the firmware installed on a device.

Does anyone have any other suggestions? I'm pretty desperate here.